# VIM language syntax

Tags: vim, macvim

I am interested in understanding this from the point of view of the VIM grammar:

The general syntax for the operations is (as per vimtutor):

```
operator [number] motion
```

However, for some operators like `f`, the syntax is:

```
[number] f motion
```

I find this confusing and mess it up almost every time.  Could someone please point out the logic (from the VIM Language perspective)?

Thanks.

Comment: It really is `[number] operator [number] motion`: `d3w` deletes 3 words, as does `3dw`. `3d5w` deletes 15.

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes **`f` is not an operator but a motion**: `fx` *moves* the cursor to the next appearance of `x`.

See this example for clarification:

- `dfx` "delete find x" deletes everything up to (including) the next x
- `d5fx` deletes to 5th x (including)

Both examples follow the grammar `operator [number] motion`:

- `d` operator
- `5` number
- `fx` motion

Looking at the `f`-command this way may clear up your confusion.

Motions are generally used to move the cursor around. They can be prepended by an operator (another example: `j` *moves* to line below, `dj` *applies delete-operator* to line below, `5dj` does it 5 times).

Answer (score 2):

`f` is not an operator so there's no reason to assume it should work like an operator.

`f` is a motion… and it pretty much works like a motion, as expected.

See `:help operator` for the complete list of available operators and take a look at the section to which `:help f` belongs.